# How to listen directly to a native event on the root element of a component in Nativescript-Vue?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

```
  <GridLayout columns="auto, *" rows="*" @tap="openDrawer">
      <Label text="Edit" @tap.native="goToEdit" col="1"></Label>
  </GridLayout>
```

Generally, in vue.js we use .native postfix to call native child component event. I am having a problem with ".native" in native-script-vue. If I use an event without ".native" postfix both parent and child event are triggering. I want to only Trigger child element.

Comment: Is it specific to Android?

Comment: Actually, I have tested it on android only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native postfix (`.native`) is designated to be used on custom components in order to track events of root element. If you use it with actual elements like `Label` above, it will silently fail. It's never going to trigger the event.

In general, it's not best practice to add multiple tap listeners around same area.